# How to add differentiate series result to another column from index 0 in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

> Here is data frame df1 and taken A column series.

```
df1

  A   B 
0 10  SLC
1 20  MNS
2 60  LLK
3 40  GNT
4 22  VJZ
5 06  NLR

I have differentiated the series with the below code.

df1['difference'] = df1['A'].diff().fillna(0) 

df1

  A   B    difference
0 10  SLC     0 <<---- place 10-20 = -10 value here
1 20  MNS   -10 <<---- place 20-60 = -40 value here 
2 60  LLK   -40 <<---- place 60-40 =  20 value here
3 40  GNT    20        ..............
4 22  VJZ    18        ..............
5 06  NLR    16        ..............
```

> How to place the difference between 10 and 20 in the '0'th index of
> 'difference' column and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change default `1` to `-1` for difference with following row:

```
df1['difference'] = df1['A'].diff(-1).fillna(df1['A']) 
print (df1)
    A    B  difference
0  10  SLC       -10.0
1  20  MNS       -40.0
2  60  LLK        20.0
3  40  GNT        18.0
4  22  VJZ        16.0
5   6  NLR         6.0
```